# Create a function CheckDidget

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am trying to create a function based on this "Algorithm" below. I basically need to pass a string in a single var and then have it run the function below.

---

The check digit calculation is as follows: each position is assigned a value; for the digits 0 to 9 this is the value of the digits, for the letters A to Z this is 10 to 35, for the filler < this is 0. The value of each position is then multiplied by its weight; the weight of the first position is 7, of the second it is 3, and of the third it is 1, and after that the weights repeat 7, 3, 1, etcetera. All values are added together and the remainder of the final value divided by 10 is the check digit.

So If i passed the following:

057607332

The multiplier is based on the position in the string. First position is 7, second is 3, third is 1 and then it repeats; 731, 731 etc

So:

0 * 7

5 * 3

7 * 1

6 * 7

0 * 3

7 * 1

3 * 7

3 * 3

2 * 1

That gives a total of 103. You divide that by 10 and you get 10.3

So the final value returned would be the remainder which is 3.

I just need a little help creating a function to handle a string its passed to run this equation on it. Any advice on where to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate the input string and look at each character individually. If the character is a digit, use the value of the digit, but if it is an alphabetical character, you can either lookup the value of the character in an array you've defined, or do some calculation based on the ASCII value of the character.

Alternating the multiplier between 7, 3, 1 is accomplished by using modulus (%) on your iteration variable. The remainder is also determined using modulus.

Here is the core of the code. You just need to handle the logic of when you encounter an alphabetical character. http://jsfiddle.net/swsKG/

```
/**
 * Takes an input string of digits and characters.
 * @param {string} input
 * @returns {int} The remainder.
 */
function calculate(input) {
    var multipliers = [7, 3, 1];
    var sum = 0;
    // Iterate each character in the input string.
    for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        // Get the index position of the next multiplier, using modulus.
        var multiplierIndex = (i % multipliers.length);
        var multiplier = multipliers[multiplierIndex];
        var char = input[i];
        // Check if char is a digit or a character.
        // If it is a character, get the appropriate int value.
        if(isNaN(char)) {
            // Not a number, so get the correct value.
            alert(char);
        } else {
            // Add to the sum.
            sum += char * multiplier;   
        }
    }
    // Return the remainder.
    return sum % 10;
};

// Testing.
var result = calculate("057607332"); // Result is 3.
```

Comment: Amazing.. thanks so much! I assume i just need to create a key value pair and then when i know what the number equivalent is to the letter i somehow use that. Could you tell me where I would pass the letters value?